# PostgreSQL: best way to join small subsets of large tables

Tags: postgresql, join, correlated-subquery

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 on a Windows machine. 
Let's say I have a clients table with 4 million records and an orders table with 25 million records.
However, I am interested in my New York clients only. There are only 5,000 New York clients who placed 15,000 orders, i.e. a drastically smaller subset.

What is the best way to retrieve the client ids and the total number of orders ever placed by New York clients?

Is a correlated subquery like

```
Select c.clientid
, ( select count(orders.clientid) from orders where orders.clientid = c.clientid) as NumOrders

From clients c
WHERE c.city = 'New York'
```

faster than a join like

```
Select c.clientid
,coalesce(o.NumOrders,0) as NumOrders

From clients c

Left outer join
( select clientid, count(*) as NumOrders from orders group by clientid ) o
on c.clientid = o.clientid

WHERE c.city = 'New York'
```

because the latter spends most of the time counting records which are then discarded since they don't relate to New York clients?
Or is there a better way?

Thank you!

PS Yes, I know, I should look at the execution plan, but I am writing this from home and I don't have a database with millions of records to test this on.

Answer (score 2):

As you alluded to, the only way to *truly* know is to compare the execution plans. In fact, the best way would be to use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, so that it actually executes the query and inserts the results into output with the estimates, so you can get a sense of the query planner versus reality.

However, in general, what I would do in a situation like this would probably be to create a *temp table* for client subset and then `JOIN` that to the `orders` table. You could optionally use `WITH` instead to do everything in one query.

So, something like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_clients AS
SELECT c.clientid
FROM clients c
WHERE c.city = 'New York'
ORDER BY c.clientid;

SELECT *
FROM orders AS o
JOIN tmp_clients AS c ON (o.clientid = c.clientid)
ORDER BY o.clientid;
```

This way, `tmp_clients` contains only the New York clients -- ~5K rows -- and it's that table that will be joined to the orders table.

You could also, to optimize further, create an index on the temp table (on the clientid) and then `ANALYZE` it before doing the `JOIN` to ensure that the JOIN is done purely on the index. You'd want to check the query plans in each case to see the relative difference (or just keep this in mind if the `JOIN` isn't quite as fast as you would like).

**Response to comment from @poshest:**

That sounds like the *temp tables* are stacking up, which would increase the memory footprint, and, for a long-running connection, functionality appear to be a memory leak.

In that case, it wouldn't be a true leak, though, as *temp tables* are scoped to a connection. They disappear automatically, but not until after the connection ends. However, you can make them disappear right away when you're done with them. Simply `DROP` the table as you would any other once you're done with them, and I suspect you'll be able to call the function a bunch of times -- on the same connection -- without the same sort of monotonic memory footprint increase.

Comment: I have used your approach in a function and found that calling it many times caused [some kind of memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739289/node-calling-postgres-function-with-temp-tables-causing-memory-leak?noredirect=1#comment61084654_36739289).Have you had any experience with this, or ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Added info to post. I looked at the link in your comment after, and it appears you already tried dropping the table without resolving the leak, which is interesting. I'll leave my modified post inline for the added info. It's possible, perhaps, there is a JavaScript-library-specific element here; I've not before tried accessing Postgres directly from JavaScript myself -- always through REST calls to a *Django* backend API. I have used this general approach before using Python's *psycopg2* library and Perl's *DBD::Pg* library, and have not encountered this type of issue before.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you're using a subquery that will have to execute at least once per matching client id number. It *will* perform poorly.

In the second case, you're using a left outer join on a subquery, which is a *little* odd. It will preserve values for clients who have no orders. This is a little bit like talking about customers who have never bought anything--are they really customers? I'm going to say "No", because this is my answer and I can make up anything I like. But I've seen cases where it *does* make sense to talk about clients you've never worked for. (Law firms sometimes have clients who have no billable hours.)

Anyway . . .

You're almost certainly better off with a simple, straightforward expression of what you're trying to count.

```
select o.clientid, count(*)
from orders o
inner join clients c on c.clientid = o.clientid
       and c.city = 'New York'
group by o.clientid;
```

You'll want an index on "city".

---

I built, populated, and indexed some tables with random(ish) data. The simple, straightforward query was faster by an order of magnitude.

```
explain analyze
Select c.clientid
      ,coalesce(o.NumOrders,0) as NumOrders
From clients c
Left outer join
    ( select clientid, count(*) as NumOrders from orders group by clientid ) o
on c.clientid = o.clientid
WHERE c.city = 'New York';
```

```
"Merge Right Join  (cost=4813633.08..5022834.83 rows=5200 width=12) (actual time=105751.121..117901.326 rows=5000 loops=1)"
"  Merge Cond: (orders.clientid = c.clientid)"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4799762.91..4996891.51 rows=962770 width=4) (actual time=105702.262..117735.305 rows=1000000 loops=1)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=4799762.91..4862263.21 rows=25000120 width=4) (actual time=105688.877..113148.881 rows=25000000 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: orders.clientid"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 342176kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..360621.20 rows=25000120 width=4) (actual time=14.866..35814.499 rows=25000000 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=13870.18..13883.18 rows=5200 width=4) (actual time=39.536..40.241 rows=5000 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: c.clientid"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 427kB"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on clients c  (cost=144.73..13549.22 rows=5200 width=4) (actual time=29.556..30.638 rows=5000 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((city)::text = 'New York'::text)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on clients_city_idx  (cost=0.00..143.43 rows=5200 width=0) (actual time=29.538..29.538 rows=5000 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((city)::text = 'New York'::text)"
"Total runtime: 118027.256 ms"
```

```
explain analyze
select o.clientid, count(*)
from orders o
inner join clients c on c.clientid = o.clientid
       and c.city = 'New York'
group by o.clientid;
```

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=595747.05..596315.80 rows=32500 width=4) (actual time=9167.518..9179.855 rows=1250 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=595747.05..595828.30 rows=32500 width=4) (actual time=9167.504..9174.135 rows=31336 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: o.clientid"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 432kB"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=13614.22..593311.47 rows=32500 width=4) (actual time=3.055..9123.568 rows=31336 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (o.clientid = c.clientid)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on orders o  (cost=0.00..360621.20 rows=25000120 width=4) (actual time=0.041..3833.387 rows=25000000 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=13549.22..13549.22 rows=5200 width=4) (actual time=2.915..2.915 rows=5000 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 176kB"
"                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on clients c  (cost=144.73..13549.22 rows=5200 width=4) (actual time=0.672..1.769 rows=5000 loops=1)"
"                          Recheck Cond: ((city)::text = 'New York'::text)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on clients_city_idx  (cost=0.00..143.43 rows=5200 width=0) (actual time=0.658..0.658 rows=5000 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: ((city)::text = 'New York'::text)"
"Total runtime: 9180.291 ms"
```

Comment: I do absolutely want to preserve values for clients who have no orders. There are many situations where it makes sense to identify and analyse such cases: one may to classify clients by the number of orders placed, for example. Those who didn't place any may be targeted with specific marketing strategies. Or one may build reports on the number of orders in specific periods, e.g. to identify the clients who didn't place any order in 2013.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to build some random data. Do I understand correctly that you had 5200 New York clients and 962770 orders in total (not just from NY)?

Comment: 5000 clients in New York; 25 million orders altogether.

Comment: I tested this on a similar database. Initially I was getting 52 seconds for the join and 29 for the correlated subquery. It turned out that work_mem was set to 1MB only. I changed it to 500MB and now I get 21 seconds for the join vs 29 for the correlated subquery.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous did you ever compare how khampson's approach performed against Mike's approach?  I used to use Mike's approach in my SQL Server work, thinking query optimizer would do the best job. A colleague taught me khampson's approach, and it was almost invariably faster, often by an order of magnitude (in your stated case of joining small subsets from large tables). I came to your post wanting to know if I needed to usurp the optimiser with khampson's approach in Postgresql too, but you didn't comment on how it worked for you