# Node calling postgres function with temp tables causing "memory leak"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a node.js program calling a Postgres (Amazon RDS micro instance) function, `get_jobs` within a transaction, 18 times a second using the `node-postgres` package by brianc.

The node code is just an enhanced version of [brianc's basic client pooling example](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), roughly like...

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://username:password@server/database";

function getJobs(cb) {
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    if (err) return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    client.query("BEGIN;");
    client.query('select * from get_jobs()', [], function(err, result) {
      client.query("COMMIT;");
      done(); //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
      if (err) console.error('error running query', err);
      cb(err, result);
    });
  });
}

function poll() {
  getJobs(function(jobs) {
    // process the jobs
  });
  setTimeout(poll, 55);
}

poll(); // start polling
```

So Postgres is getting:

```
2016-04-20 12:04:33 UTC:172.31.9.180(38446):XXX@XXX:[5778]:LOG:  statement: BEGIN;
2016-04-20 12:04:33 UTC:172.31.9.180(38446):XXX@XXX:[5778]:LOG:  execute <unnamed>: select * from get_jobs();
2016-04-20 12:04:33 UTC:172.31.9.180(38446):XXX@XXX:[5778]:LOG:  statement: COMMIT;
```

... repeated every 55ms.

`get_jobs` is written with temp tables, something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_jobs (
) RETURNS TABLE (
  ...
) AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  _nowstamp bigint; 
BEGIN

  -- take the current unix server time in ms
  _nowstamp := (select extract(epoch from now()) * 1000)::bigint;  

  --  1. get the jobs that are due
  CREATE TEMP TABLE jobs ON COMMIT DROP AS
  select ...
  from really_big_table_1 
  where job_time < _nowstamp;

  --  2. get other stuff attached to those jobs
  CREATE TEMP TABLE jobs_extra ON COMMIT DROP AS
  select ...
  from really_big_table_2 r
    inner join jobs j on r.id = j.some_id

  ALTER TABLE jobs_extra ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

  -- 3. return the final result with a join to a third big table
  RETURN query (

    select je.id, ...
    from jobs_extra je
      left join really_big_table_3 r on je.id = r.id
    group by je.id

  );

END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I've used [the temp table pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084540/2036135) because I know that `jobs` will always be a small extract of rows from `really_big_table_1`, in hopes that this will scale better than a single query with multiple joins and multiple where conditions. (I used this to great effect with SQL Server and I don't trust any query optimiser now, but please tell me if this is the wrong approach for Postgres!)

The query runs in 8ms on small tables (as measured from node), ample time to complete one job "poll" before the next one starts.

Problem: After about 3 hours of polling at this rate, the Postgres server runs out of memory and crashes.

What I tried already...

- If I re-write the function without temp tables, Postgres doesn't run out of memory, but I use the temp table pattern a lot, so this isn't a solution.
- If I stop the node program (which kills the 10 connections it uses to run the queries) the memory frees up.  Merely making node wait a minute between polling sessions doesn't have the same effect, so there are obviously resources that the Postgres backend associated with the pooled connection is keeping.
- If I run a `VACUUM` while polling is going on, it has no effect on memory consumption and the server continues on its way to death.
- Reducing the polling frequency only changes the amount of time before the server dies.
- Adding `DISCARD ALL;` after each `COMMIT;` has no effect.
- Explicitly calling `DROP TABLE jobs; DROP TABLE jobs_extra;` after `RETURN query ()` instead of `ON COMMIT DROP`s on the `CREATE TABLE`s. Server still crashes.
- Per CFrei's suggestion, added `pg.defaults.poolSize = 0` to the node code in an attempt to disable pooling.  The server still crashed, but took much longer and swap went much higher (second spike) than all the previous tests which looked like the first spike below.  I found out later that `pg.defaults.poolSize = 0` [may not disable pooling as expected](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/319).

[image: Swap memory usage on Postgres server]

- On the basis of [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/routine-vacuuming.html): "Temporary tables cannot be accessed by autovacuum. Therefore, appropriate vacuum and analyze operations should be performed via session SQL commands.", I tried to run a `VACUUM` from the node server (as some attempt to make `VACUUM` an "in session" command).  I couldn't actually get this test working. I have many objects in my database and `VACUUM`, operating on all objects, was taking too long to execute each job iteration.  Restricting `VACUUM` just to the temp tables was impossible - (a) you can't run `VACUUM` in a transaction and (b) outside the transaction the temp tables don't exist. :P  EDIT: Later on the Postgres IRC forum, a helpful chap explained that VACUUM isn't relevant for temp tables themselves, but can be useful to clean up the rows created and deleted from `pg_attributes` that TEMP TABLES cause. In any case, VACUUMing "in session" wasn't the answer.
- `DROP TABLE ... IF EXISTS` before the `CREATE TABLE`, instead of `ON COMMIT DROP`. Server still dies.
- `CREATE TEMP TABLE (...)` and `insert into ... (select...)` instead of `CREATE TEMP TABLE ... AS`, instead of `ON COMMIT DROP`. Server dies.

So is `ON COMMIT DROP` not releasing all the associated resources?  What else could be holding memory?  How do I release it?

Comment: Can you show the Node code that you're using to perform the query?

Comment: Does this bug continues when you use `require('pg-native')` instead of `pg`?

What about if you create a new connection every time you ask for a pool connection? `pg.defaults.poolSize = 0`.

Comment: @robertklep I've added the code.  @ CFrei will report back once we've tested - it takes a while for each cycle.

Comment: [I don't understand this node-js stuff] Does this mean that you start a fresh connection to the DBMS every 55ms , and do not close it properly?

Comment: @wildplasser the node code is using node-postgres module to pool connections.  Used this way, node-postgres creates up to 10 connections (the default, and what we're using) and re-uses them to prevent the expensive database connection set-up and destroy processes. Read more about it here https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/pg

Comment: Looking at the function: it can probably be rewritten in plain SQL, avoiding the plpgsql overhead.

Comment: @wildplasser that may be true, but that sounds like a minor optimisation and won't save my server from crashing. Are you suggesting that it might solve my problem? If so, please provide code. I attempted it quickly just now, and ran into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353438/postgres-doesnt-recognize-temp-table-in-function

Comment: @CFrei we used `require('pg').native` instead of `require('pg-native')` as you suggested so we didn't have to re-write our code. There was no change - server still ran out of memory. Please reply if you think using `require('pg-native')` directly will make a material change, but I believe `require('pg').native` is just a wrapper for `require('pg-native')`. Still testing the `pg.defaults.poolSize = 0` idea.

Comment: A work-around could possibly be to periodically close and reopen the connections, say: after a few thousands requests. A prepared statement (or a set of them) could also be a way to avoid plpgsql (which I suspect to be the resoure leaker)

Comment: This is all just a workaround if it works. There is a "cleanup-when-idle" parameter in the pool, maybe you can gest best of both (pool + regular cleanup of connections). Can you check with another language/framework, if your problem persists? I'm quite sure its something with the database, not with nodejs...

Comment: @wildplasser yes, we're considering that option.  It's a bit of a hack, but might be the best solution.  Meantime, re plpsql leaking, I'll look into it. Grateful for some more detail about how you imagine structuring that. I've never used that feature before.

Comment: @CFrei the server still crashed with `pg.defaults.poolSize = 0`. Perhaps setting poolSize = 0 [doesn't work](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/319). Your idea of testing with another framework is good - we could even just start with a shell script and psql. Before that I shall try the client.end() pattern, suggested in the link.

Comment: @poshest why are using a transaction to execute a single `SELECT`? This isn't what transactions are for.

Comment: @vitaly-t before this memory leak caper, I had no transactions around the query.  I only added them in an attempt to get `ON COMMIT DROP` to work. `ON COMMIT DROP` is also a recent attempt to get this working. Prior to that I simply had `DROP TABLE jobs; DROP TABLE jobs_extra;` after the `RETURN query`

Comment: @poshest can you see an improvement when using pg-promise from the answer I published here? At the very least it guarantees proper use of connections and transactions, which is a good start for you trying to nail the problem ;) Who knows, it may be the final solution, if the problem is gone completely ;)

Comment: @poshest I have added another update there that's also very important.

Comment: Only more idea: by default a pool connection is closed if it is idle for 30 seconds. Can you sleep your application - with no connection actively used - for a minute every n minutes? At least for testing? If the pool fails to close a connection, why don't you just drop the pool and use plain connections?

Comment: @CFrei that's quite clever, I didn't get that from your earlier description.  We did try pausing the activity, but only for 10 seconds, less than the default 30 second connection timeout. Unfortunately, as you say, it's only good as a test and could never be the basis of a production solution. Meantime, we're testing the "plain connections" now, and it's looking good, but it's also not a production solution. :P To that end, I'm remonstrating with [node-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool/issues/133) (on which node-postgres pooling is built) to add a connection TTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CTEs to create partial result sets instead of temp tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_jobs (
) RETURNS TABLE (
  ...
) AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  _nowstamp bigint; 
BEGIN

  -- take the current unix server time in ms
  _nowstamp := (select extract(epoch from now()) * 1000)::bigint;  

  RETURN query (

    --  1. get the jobs that are due
    WITH jobs AS (

      select ...
      from really_big_table_1 
      where job_time < _nowstamp;

    --  2. get other stuff attached to those jobs
    ), jobs_extra AS (

      select ...
      from really_big_table_2 r
        inner join jobs j on r.id = j.some_id

    ) 

    -- 3. return the final result with a join to a third big table
    select je.id, ...
    from jobs_extra je
      left join really_big_table_3 r on je.id = r.id
    group by je.id

  );

END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The planner will evaluate each block in sequence the way I wanted to achieve with temp tables.

I know this doesn't directly solve the memory leak issue (I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with Postgres' implementation of them, at least the way they manifest on the RDS configuration).

However, the query works, it is query planned the way I was intending and the memory usage is stable now after 3 days of running the job and my server doesn't crash.

I didn't change the node code at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I used this to great effect with SQL Server and I don't trust any query optimiser now

Then don't use them. You can still execute queries directly, as shown below.

> but please tell me if this is the wrong approach for Postgres!

It is not a completely wrong approach, it's just a very awkward one, as you are trying to create something that's been implemented by others for a much easier use. As a result, you are making many mistakes that can lead to many problems, including memory leaks.

Compare to the simplicity of the exact same example that uses [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')();
var conString = "postgres://username:password@server/database";
var db = pgp(conString);

function getJobs() {
    return db.tx(function (t) {
        return t.func('get_jobs');
    });
}

function poll() {
    getJobs()
        .then(function (jobs) {
            // process the jobs
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // error
        });

    setTimeout(poll, 55);
}

poll(); // start polling
```

Gets even simpler when using ES6 syntax:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')();
var conString = "postgres://username:password@server/database";
var db = pgp(conString);

function poll() {
    db.tx(t=>t.func('get_jobs'))
        .then(jobs=> {
            // process the jobs
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // error
        });

    setTimeout(poll, 55);
}

poll(); // start polling
```

The only thing that I didn't quite understand in your example - the use of a transaction to execute a single `SELECT`. This is not what transactions are generally for, as you are not changing any data. I assume you were trying to shrink a real piece of code you had that changes some data also.

In case you don't need a transaction, your code can be further reduced to:

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')();
var conString = "postgres://username:password@server/database";
var db = pgp(conString);

function poll() {
    db.func('get_jobs')
        .then(jobs=> {
            // process the jobs
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // error
        });

    setTimeout(poll, 55);
}

poll(); // start polling
```

**UPDATE**

It would be a dangerous approach, however, not to control the end of the previous request, which also may create memory/connection issues.

A safe approach should be:

```
function poll() {
    db.tx(t=>t.func('get_jobs'))
        .then(jobs=> {
            // process the jobs

            setTimeout(poll, 55);
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // error

            setTimeout(poll, 55);
        });
}
```

Comment: I assumed that the transaction is only used to trigger the `ON COMMIT DROP` of the temporary tables, as a sort of garbage collection.

Comment: @robertklep, ok, that may be, I just wasn't clear on that part. Anyhow, I provided the example with a transaction, if needed ;)

Comment: Hey vitaly, I appreciate that your library has many great features, but your answer would be more persuasive if you identified where in MY code are the "mistakes that can lead to many problems, including memory leaks". Having said that, I will give your library a go and let you know if it solves my problem.

Comment: @poshest any luck there? :)

Comment: Hey Vitaly, I was pretty convinced the problem was on Postgres, and that turned out to be the case (see my answer). So I didn't end up needing to change the node code.  I'll certainly use your library if we decide to adopt the promise pattern app-wide.