# Postgres CTE with refcursors

Tags: postgresql, ref-cursor

How can I open multiple refcursors using expressions generated in a CTE?

I use refcursors to return multiple record sets from the same function, and CTEs for data set re-use throughout processing.

I would use temp tables, but I'm [scarred after this experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739289/node-calling-postgres-function-with-temp-tables-causing-memory-leak).

I tried this, but it results in a syntax error:

```
WITH 
  expr1 (
    select ... from ...
  ),
  expr2 (
    select ... from expr1 inner join ...
  ),
  expr3 (
    OPEN refcursor1 FOR select ... from expr2
  )
  OPEN refcursor2 FOR select ... from expr2 inner join ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it that way, because you cannot embed a PL/pgSQL statement (`OPEN`) in an SQL statement.

You'll have to run the query twice if you want two `refcursors`.

Perhaps you should find out what was the problem with the temporary table — for example, check the memory context dump in the log.